# Why do my floated elements break on smaller resolutions if there is enough space?

Tags: html, css, less

My floated elements look the way they should on a wide viewport but when I scale it down a little (from 1920px width to somewhere around 1100px width) they just break and stack vertically. There is enough room for them to still be floated at that resolution, I can't seem to figure out what is the problem.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="page-content" class="page homepage">
    <div id="homepage-cards">

        <div class="homepage-card">
            <img src="{{asset("img/content/web_development.png")}}" alt="web development" />
            <h2>Web development</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="homepage-card">
            <img src="{{asset("img/content/web_development.png")}}" alt="web development" />
            <h2>Web development</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="homepage-card">
            <img src="{{asset("img/content/web_development.png")}}" alt="web development" />
            <h2>Web development</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="homepage-card">
            <img src="{{asset("img/content/web_development.png")}}" alt="web development" />
            <h2>Web development</h2>
        </div>        

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my LESS:

```
div.page.homepage {
    position: relative;
    background: @skyscrapers no-repeat center center fixed;
    .background-size(cover);
    min-height:1080px;
    z-index:10;
}

div#homepage-cards {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:50%;
    .translate(-50%, -50%);

    div.homepage-card {
        display:inline-block;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        padding:56px 60px 100px 60px;
        float:left;
        margin-right:30px;
        margin-bottom:30px;
        &:nth-child(2n+2) {
            margin-right:0;
        }
        &:nth-child(3) {
            clear:left;
        }
        h2 {
            margin-top:25px;
            text-transform: lowercase;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    }

}
```

This is how those cards look on a wide viewport:
[image: Cards on a wide viewport]

This is how they look on a bit smaller viewport (while still having enough space to stay in two columns):
[image: Cards on a slightly smaller viewport]

**It seems that it's the parent "inline-block" element shrinking together with the viewport width even though its position is absolute and it still has a lot of room around it.**

How can I stop that element shrinking until it doesn't have enough room?

Comment: Post a working code snippet that reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (...) while still having enough space to stay in two columns

No, they don't. You have set the `#homepage-cards` to be `left: 50%`, which basically means that it will be half the width of the entire viewport. Inside that half, there is not enough room for two in a row.

I'd suggest finding a different way to center them than the translate-trick you are using now, or add some media-queries for when it's above/below the breaking point.

Comment: So I basically tricked myself with the left:50% and translate combination. This caused me not to notice that those elements have reduced space to grow. What do you think about making a block element translated vertically to -50% with top:50% and having an inline-block container in it to center the cards via text-align:center?

Comment: Okay what I described works, I am accepting your answer :). Thank you!